# resample data to match with timestamp based on another variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that is in the following form:

```
Name   Value  Timetag                 
a      1    2020-07-31 00:22:00.000
a      2    2020-07-31 00:24:00.000 
b      1      2020-07-31 00:22:00.000
b      8      2020-07-31 00:23:00.000 
total  20     2020-07-31 00:20:00.000 
total  25     2020-07-31 00:30:00.000
```

And what I need is to have all the values in the same resolution that in total. So for that I need to resample the `Timetag` column when `Name` is not `total` so that it matches to when it is `total`. What I want to achieve next is to pivot the table and not have missing values and also to reduce the amount of rows on my dataframe. So, the result would look like this:

```
 Name   Value  Timetag                 
 a      1.3    2020-07-31 00:20:00.000 
 a      2.5    2020-07-31 00:30:00.000 
 b      2      2020-07-31 00:20:00.000 
 b      6      2020-07-31 00:30:00.000 
 total  20     2020-07-31 00:20:00.000 
 total  25     2020-07-31 00:30:00.000
```

Where `Value` of `a` and `b` would be obtained by the mean of its values between time gap between one value of `total` and the next one if you order by date f.x. the values that are in the range: [2020-07-31 00:20:00.000,2020-07-31 00:30:00.000)

Thank you!

Comment: Please paste table as simple text. Don't format it. It's difficult to work with.

Comment: @Vishnudev like that?

Comment: There's no difference between input and expected output. @enriqueqs

Comment: @Vishnudev sorry I did not change some of the values when editing

Comment: Can you explain how you got your expected output using some sample numbers?

Comment: @Vishnudev `Value` of `a` and `b` would be obtained by the mean of its values between time gap between one value of `total` and the next one if you order by date f.x. the values that are in the range: [2020-07-31 00:20:00.000,2020-07-31 00:30:00.000)